# Cart Price Rule uses Configurable's Category instead of Simple's

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want a cart price rule to only be active for certain simple products under a configurable product, but so far I've been unable to accomplish this. Any ideas?

One thing I've tried was to create a category to assign all simple products to, but Magento seems to only be checking the configurable product's category in this case.

Here's the rule:

-ACTIONS: Apply 20 percent of product price discount.

if ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
Category is not one of 6, 12, 14, 27

I've tried adding an additional SKU condition ("is not one of...") with no success.

Comment: Did you try using a condition `where` -  `SKU` - `is one of` - `{list of sku's}`?

Comment: Yeah, didn't have any luck targeting SKU's either.

Comment: if targeting the SKU's didn't work then something else is wrong with your rule?

Comment: Hmm, @Haim can you please take a look at my edit and let me know if you see anything?

Comment: what if you remove the category filter and just target the SKU's that you **want** in your promo?

Comment: Because we want the promo to cover hundreds of products and only exclude a handful.

Comment: OK - what if you remove the category filter and keep only the filter that excludes the SKU's you don't want?

Comment: is it not so that the SKUs in the cart are the simple product SKUs and therefor do not exactly match the (parent) SKUs in the catgeory?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a second rule that applies the discount to specific SKU's belonging to the categories set as exempt in the first rule. Seems to work well.